# MacBook Pro Hardware & Software Issues under warranty

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, warranty

I have a **MacBook Pro(13-inch Retina display)**, bought on **27 November 2015, from Bangalore India**.

Last Monday it got some booting problem, and I was not able to go forward from the boot screen, always got stuck up at OS booting view.

I have given the device to service center, and after one day I got a response from service team saying that **device dose not have any hardware issue, it might be a OS issue**, so they need to format all data and re install the OS. I allow them to format all data.

For next two days I didn't got any update from the service center. Then I tried to call Apple Customer Support Team for more information on the status of the device. After 2 days recursive trying we got chance to talk to the service center people. And got an update that,

> There is some issue with some chip, which they want to replace with a new one. So they are going to order it from the warehouse. That will take around 4 days to ship from there. And if it is not there it will take more time to repair and get back the device.

I am a Developer by profession, I have lot of pending work due to this issue, also lost lot of my work which I need to do again. There is no Physical Damage to the machine. Service center team is not ready to provide me a machine as a placeholder till my machine gets back.

I would like know, where and how I can ask Apple for getting a new machine instead of existing one, as there is no idea to anyone from Apple Support Team and Service Team when the issue will get resolved.

And this particular machine is under warranty.
Please help me out on this.
Many Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just visit Apple's support page:

[Apple Support](https://support.apple.com)

There you'll be able to check if your product is still under warranty, and contact Apple to ask for a replacement.

It doesn't seem clear to me whether you actually purchased the computer from Apple, or from a local retailer, so they might not be able to help you with repair progress information from a local shop.

Comment: This likely won’t help for someone in India where all repair and sales and service go through third parties. Unless the hardware was bought from another country with local Apple establishing warranty support from Apple - this likely needs to wait for the parts to arrive and the service to be done.

Comment: @bmike This question is more than a year old, but are you actually sure that is the case in India? - My own country does not have an Apple presence, but we can still call Apple in the US for example to request a replacement.

Comment: Yes - still today there’s no Apple official sales or support in India. https://www.apple.com/in/buy/ Importing tech to large growing countries like Brazil and India is quite political from all signs and public reports. I am sure about the service side - the channel through which the serialized hardware is sold funds the warranty work and thus constrains the options.

Comment: @bmike But here there's no Apple official sales or support either. However, we can just call the international Apple support phone numbers - even though they are in the US and we're not, they will handle warranty cases for example.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. You would want to buy insurance or pay for a rental or loaner equipment available to cover the time when a warranty repair is ongoing. Also, your warranty is only for hardware and not software.

Apple used to provide loaner for service (and may still do so) to businesses as part of the [Apple Retail joint venture program](https://www.apple.com/retail/business/jointventure/terms.html).

Also, there can be a different level of service worldwide when Apple establishes a local retail store presence versus ones where Apple relies on third party authorized agents (like in India presently). If the third party wants to have more parts on stock to speed repairs, then the prices will be higher than a third party that carries no stock and has to order each only when needed from out of the country but can charge less (or profit more) from the costs allowed per repair from Apple for warranty service.